# Calculate location on a line depending on progression

Tags: ios, opengl-es

I need to do a simple animation in OpenGL.

I want an object to move between 2 points. How do I calculate the location with the progression (0-1) of the animation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `Beg` and `End` are vector-valued and `Alpha` is your interpolation value:

```
InterpolatedPoint = ((1 - Alpha) * Beg) + (Alpha * End)
```